# Separate decimal point with colon

Tags: java

I want to format decimal to string separated with colon (`:`). For example `296.00` to `296:00`.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            amount = Double.valueOf(df.format(amount));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace should do.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
amount = Double.valueOf(df.format(amount));
String newFormat = String.valueOf(amount).replace('.',':');
```

Comment: That's dangerous: if you run this code in, say, Germany, France or Holland the output will be `296,00`, not `296:00` as requested. You need to specify the Locale (`Locale.US`) for this to work reliably.

Comment: Good Catch, But Internalization is not a matter of concern to Vivek. However, @Vivek Shankar - Please refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String%29 - if you consider locale.

Comment: @SrikanthA You cannot assume that DecimalFormat outputs a point as the decimal separator, unless you explicitly specify the Locale. And you're not just writing this answer for Vivek (that's not the point of StackOverflow, plus you don't know in which country Vivek works/lives), you're writing your answer for the whole world. Your code does not work for someone who lives in  **majority** of countries in the world that use a comma as the decimal separator. You should use `new DecimalFormat("#.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))` to correct your code.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but incase someone stumbles upon this later I found a better solution...

You can use DecimalFormatSymbols to replace the default decimal separator for your formatter taking into account the users locale.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(':');
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00.00", symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(45.45889));
```